# tikz picture inside a tabular environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, standalone

Why does the following code fail to compile?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every path/.style={line width=0.66em}}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
 $<$ 1 hour & \tikz \draw (0,0) -- (2.874cm,0) node[anchor=west] {28.74\%};
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) In such cases you should always post the exact error message(s) you get. Also the version number of the package/class in question is also useful.

Comment: Using `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}` instead of `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tikz` option of `standalone` generates one page for all `tikzpicture`s it finds, because it also enables the `multi` option. For this it will box and discard everything which is outside of such environments. 
It is not intended to be used with `\tikz` inside a `tabular`. I recommend to drop the `tikz` option and load the `tikz` package manually instead.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every path/.style={line width=0.66em}}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
 $<$ 1 hour & \tikz \draw (0,0) -- (2.874cm,0) node[anchor=west] {28.74\%};
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can we have a caption for it as well?